# Add named color from style sheet

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

**Is there is a way to add to the `matplotlib` default `_colors_full_map <class _ColorMapping>` by loading from a style sheet?**

I have looked into the following style specification methods ([guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files)) and found nothing for named colors. I would love to be able to do this with with [style.use](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/style_api.html#matplotlib.style.use). In theory I could set the cycler in a style sheet, and then use [CN notation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html) to use the custom colors, but I would need to remember the index for each color rather than the name.

Desired behavior:

```
# Set up
import matplotlib as mpl
fig, ax = mpl.pyplot.subplots()

# Import from sheet, use color name
plt.style.use('custom-style-sheet')
artist, = ax.plot(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 1], c='custom-name')
```

My current best option is to load these from a JSON file and update the `mpl.colors._colors_full_map` dictionary as a second step (along with `plt.style.use`). This would require a second file to be distributed with the `.mplstyle` file, which I do not prefer.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Why not use named colors [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html). Matplotlib already has a lot of named colors for you.

Comment: I am looking to standardize colors used for some industry specific plots. For example, I want all representations of water transfers to be red. Rather than have all end users agree to use a specific HEX for this kind of data, I would rather add a keyword "water_transfer" to the named color set that corresponds to that data.